# Adding two new elements to existing JSON array

Tags: javascript

I have the following JavaScript object which prints the following JSON using

```
var str = JSON.stringify(finalNodesData, null, 2);
console.log(str);
```

Printed JSON

```
[
  {
    "jobDate": "2023-01-03 13:48:29.402",
    "id": "b186c313-a2f3-44a8-9803-066c6d52e8a0"
  },
  {
    "jobDate": "2023-01-03 13:57:19.988",
    "id": "db182f5e-9622-42e9-bbe8-19bee4d878d4"
  }
]
```

How can I add two new elements "submitedBy" and "submitReason" to the JSON? I want my JSON to look like

```
{
    "submitedBy": "Bob Smith",
    "submitReason": "Because of an error",
    "nodeData": [
      {
        "jobDate": "2023-01-03 13:48:29.402",
        "id": "b186c313-a2f3-44a8-9803-066c6d52e8a0"
      },
      {
        "jobDate": "2023-01-03 13:57:19.988",
        "id": "db182f5e-9622-42e9-bbe8-19bee4d878d4"
      }
    ]
}
```

I want to use JavaScript variables to generate the JSON, and not concatenate strings.

Comment: you add it before you create a json, or use JSON.parse to convert it back to object, add new items and then convert back to string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note: Your new JSON is no longer an Array, but an Object.

```
finalNodesData = {};  
finalNodesData["nodeData"] = nodeData; // this is your old data
finalNodesData["submitedBy"] = "Bob Smith";
finalNodesData["submitReason"] = "Because of an error";

var str = JSON.stringify(finalNodesData, null, 2);
console.log(str);
```

Answer (score 0):

The best way of doing this is adding the data to the JavaScript object before converting it to JSON.

```js
let finalNodesData = [
  {
    jobDate: "2023-01-03 13:48:29.402",
    id: "b186c313-a2f3-44a8-9803-066c6d52e8a0"
  },
  {
    jobDate: "2023-01-03 13:57:19.988",
    id: "db182f5e-9622-42e9-bbe8-19bee4d878d4"
  }
]


const submittedBy = "Bob Smith"
const submitReason = "Because of an error"

finalNodesData = {
  submittedBy,
  submitReason,
  nodeData: finalNodesData
}

var str = JSON.stringify(finalNodesData, null, 2);


console.log(str);
```